# Restore internet after TorGuard messed it up

Tags: networking, internet

I use the TorGuard VPN client and yesterday I accidentally turned off my computer with it still connected. Now after turning my computer on this morning I can't access the internet. To make matters worse the TorGaurd client won't open now.

`ip link show` shows two interfaces the lopback `lo` and what I believe is my WiFi card `wlp107s0`. When I try and run `nmcli d connect wlp107s0` dmesg complains of `deauthenticating from ... by local choice (Reson: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)`

The TorGuard app (which I believe uses OpenVPN) obviously changed something with my network interfaces. How do I restore the correct settings?

I've been using Ubuntu for several years and am very comfortable in the terminal but unfortunately never had any reason to dig very deep into how it handles networks.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered `resolv.conf` was pointing to `127.0.0.53` changing that to `8.8.8.8` fixed the issue.

```
sudo sh -c "echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf"
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```